# WaitAll limitation

Tags: c#, .net

I heard there is limitation when using waitall  on multiple threads (# of threads to wait?). Can anyone give details?

Comment: Ive never heard of such limitation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the restriction you are referring to is not on the number of *threads*; it is on the number of *handles* being waited on. From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx) for `WaitHandle.WaitAll(WaitHandle[])`:

> On some implementations, if more than
>   64 handles are passed, a
>   NotSupportedException is thrown.

On the rare occasion that this issue has cropped, I have normally worked around it with:

```
WaitHandle[] handles = ...

foreach(var waitHandle in handles)
   waitHandle.WaitOne();
```

For completeness, the other restrictions appear to be:

> If the array contains duplicates, the
>   call fails with a
>   DuplicateWaitObjectException.
>
> The WaitAll method is not supported on
>   threads that have STAThreadAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of the STA (single-threaded apartment) limitation of a winform app?

If so, I handle this by simply checking if the 'work queue' is empty after each thread has done it's processing, and calling .WaitOne() on a single ManualResetEvent object that the main thread owns instead of using .WaitAll() at all.

Like this:

```
    moSolverEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ProcessResult(new SolverWorkInProgress());

    //Wait here until the last background thread reports in
    moSolverEvent.WaitOne();
```

And then the worker threads are doing this:

```
if (mhSolverWorkQueue.Count == 0) moSolverEvent.Set();
```

It works spectacularly well, and avoids any issues with WaitAll(), even in a WinForms app.  After all, you're not really waiting for the threads to be done... you're waiting for the WORK to be done. :-)

Just be sure to do the appropriate locking on each of these objects so your threads don't step all over each other.